# concatinate array in one string on $_POST

Tags: php

selecting more than one cities, After Submit form i want to make a single string from selected cities and store this single string to a variable.
How can i do this in php.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="city[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="City1">City1</option>
    <option value="City2">City2</option>
    <option value="City3">City3</option>
    <option value="City4">City4</option>
</select>
```

Submit

---

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php

$cities = implode(', ', $_POST['city']);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['city']` is an array so you can simply use implode function:

```
$cities = implode(', ', $_POST['city]);
```

More about implode [here](http://php.net/implode)